# Little question on nowhere dense subsets of a metric space.

Tags: metric-spaces

Suppose that $X$ is a metric space with a nowhere dense subset $A$. Say that $x$ is a point in $X \setminus A$.

Then it must be the case that there exists an $r>0$ such that $B(x,r) \cap A = \varnothing$?

Any hint would be appreciated.

Comment: What if $X=\mathbb R$ and $A=\{\frac1n:n\in\mathbb N\}$ and $x=0?$

Comment: Your statement is true if you change "nowhere dense" to "closed".